# How to add a constraint for a variable in an ODE in python?

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations, bounds, odeint

I need to solve a system of differential equations and I have a function that returns dx/dt and du/dt, but I need to add the constraint that u is in the interval [0,1]. How can I do that? So far I've been using odeint from scipy.integrate to solve it. This is the model:

```py
def model_case_1(z, t, Kmax):
    '''The input z corresponds to the current state of the system, z = [x, u, m] 
    (x is the population, u is the resistance rate and m whether there is treatment or not). 
    t is the current time.
    Kmax corresponds to the unknown parameter.
    '''
    
    x, u= z
    if t>0:
      m=1
    else:
      m=0
    dxdt =  x*(r*(1-x//(Kmax*(1-u)))-m//(k+b*u)-d)
    dudt = sigma*(m*b//((k+b*u)**2)-r*x//(Kmax*(1-u)**2))
    return [dxdt, dudt]
```

Then I estimate Kmax and I solve the ODE with:

```py
    y = odeint(model_case_1, [x0, u0], teval, args=(Kmax0,))
```

But then, of course, I get values for u bigger than 1, which cannot happen.

Comment: Is the use of integer division intentional? Is the restriction of `u` in any way natural in the theoretical model?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I just changed it because I was getting an error and then forgot about it, but yeah, it should be normal division